# Prepare all dishes with the least different ingredients - what is this problem called?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I am trying to find the best way to solve the following problem:

> A cook has to prepare $n$ dishes, and for each dish he has $k$ different recipes. Each recipe is a non-empty subset of the set $I$ of all ingredients.
>
> How can we find the smallest set of ingredients required to prepare all dishes?

I can currently write this problem as an instance of other, more general problems but I was wondering whether there's a precise, well-known name for this problem.

Here's a small example: let's say you have 5 possible ingredients $a, b, c, d, e$ and three dishes.

- Dish 1 can be prepared with either recipe $\{e\}$ or with $\{b, c\}$
- Dish 2 can be prepared with recipes $\{e\}$ or $\{a, c\}$
- Dish 3 can be prepared with recipe $\{a, b, c\}$ or $\{a, b, d\}$

You can prepare all three dishes with ingredients $\{a, b, c\}$. Ingredients $d$ and $e$ are not required in the optimal case. A greedy algorithm would have picked recipe $\{e\}$ and end up on a sub-optimal solution. And while in this case there is a recipe that includes all previous ingredients, this is not expected to be the case in general.

Some things I looked into that didn't quite work:

- Set cover: doesn't quite fit because it is okay for some ingredients not to be used at all, like $d$ and $e$ in the example.
- Assignment problem: it typically doesn't account for a single ingredient being used in multiple dishes.
- [0-1 Knapsack problem with multiple choice constraints](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037722177890108X): the formulation of the problem is the same, but it doesn't account for the "weight" of each element changing based on what's already in the knapsack: if you put recipe $\{a, b, c\}$ in the knapsack, the cost of adding recipe $\{b, c\}$ is 0.
- [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259009/matching-a-minimal-amount-of-entries-to-a-set-of-requirements-graph-theory) is very similar to mine, but I could't get pass the problem that getting the ingredients for half of recipe 1 and half of recipe 2 doesn't mean that I have a complete recipe.

Comment: @BrianTung Each dish has a choice of recipes.  Taking the union of all ingredients would be feasible but generally much larger than the smallest possible set that would enable preparing one recipe for each dish.

Comment: @RobPratt: OK, thanks, I get it now. Deleting my other comments.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I think so.  It might help to reinterpret the problem in terms of subjects/courses/prerequisites instead of dishes/recipes/ingredients.  You must take one course in each subject, and each subject/course has a set of prerequisites.  What is the smallest number of prerequisites needed to be able to graduate?

Comment: The problem is not to construct the prerequisites.  Rather, the sets of prerequisites are given, and they might or might not be distinct or overlapping.  The problem is to find a smallest set of prerequisites that together cover one course for each subject.

Comment: @Martin a small explicit example would make your question clearer.

Comment: @RobPratt The OP's (i.e. original poster's) link to the multiple-choice knapsack problem (MCKP) is not publicly accessible.  Googling, I found this: "The multiple-choice knapsack problem (MCKP) is a generalization of the ordinary knapsack problem, where the set of items is partitioned into classes. The binary choice of taking an item is replaced by the selection of exactly one item out of each class of items."  So, although I still don't fully comprehend the question, I am convinced that I was misinterpreting the question.  I have deleted my comments and answer.

Comment: To the OP:  See my previous comment.  I agree with Brian Tung.  For anyone unfamiliar with the multiple choice knapsack problem, it would help greatly, if (in long-winded style) you would edit your question to very carefully explain the constraints, with at least one very clear example.

Comment: I have added an example now, hopefully it will clear up any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows. Let $I_{d,r} \subseteq I$ be the set of ingredients required for dish $d$ and recipe $r$.   Let binary decision variable $x_{d,r}$ indicate that dish $d$ uses recipe $r$.  Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether ingredient $i$ is used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i\in I} y_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^k x_{d,r} &= 1 &&\text{for $d\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag1\\
x_{d,r} &\le y_i &&\text{for $d\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $r\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, and $i\in I_{d,r}$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ makes sure that each dish uses one of its recipes.
Constraint $(2)$ forces all the required ingredients to be used for each chosen dish and recipe.